# How to invoke an instance by its property in Python?

Tags: python

I have defined a class, and the objects in this class have some properties `pp1`, `pp2`, etc.

```
class example(object):
   def __init__(self,pp1,pp2,...):
       self.pp1=pp1
       self.pp2=pp2
       ...

for x in range (0,100):
    ll[x]=example(pp1[x],pp2[x],...) # pp1[x] pp2[x] are defined somewhere else

ll[30]=example(30.0,40.0,...)
```

I have defined many instances `ll[x]` of class `example`. These properties pp1,pp2, etc. are unique for each instance.

Usually, we call it with:

```
ll[x].method()
```

If I don't know the name of instance (i.e., `ll[x]` in this case), is it possible to determine the instance with one or more of its properties? For example, I hope to invoke an instance whose `pp1` is '30.0' (and `pp2` is 40.0), but I don't know its name. (`ll[30]` in this case)

In SQL, it may looks like `Select * from example where pp1=30.0 (and pp2=40.0)` and we can get `ll[30]` for its result, then we can give `.method()` to do something else.

If it is impossible, is there any alternative ways?

Addition:
Thanks to Alik for the suggestion of using filter. I think it can work for this example. But what if we do not define these instances in a list?

Comment: use filter or list comprehension?

Comment: Correct your code, I don't think that you can define a class by using 'def' statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple approach is to simply keep a list of instances internally:

```
class example(object):
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, pp1, pp2, ...):
        self.pp1 = pp1
        self.pp2 = pp2
        ...

        example.instances.append(self)
```

You can then simply filter the list `example.instances` to find the instances you need.

Or, if you want a more performant approach (with faster lookup times), you can keep a lookup table from each property value to the instances with that value, as follows:

```
class example(object):
    pp1_lookup = {}
    pp2_lookup = {}
    ...

    def __init__(self,pp1,pp2,...):
        self.pp1=pp1
        self.pp2=pp2
        ...

        example.pp1_lookup.setdefault(pp1,[]).append(self)
        example.pp2_lookup.setdefault(pp2,[]).append(self)
        ...
```

The downside of this approach is that it assumes that your `example` instances are immutable after instantiation, and that the property values are hashable (otherwise they can't be used as `dict` keys). If either of those aren't true, things become more difficult (but not impossible).

To look up an instance under this scheme, you then only need to look up the property value in the appropriate lookup table:

```
examples = example.pp1_lookup.get(30.0, [])
```

This returns a list of all `example` instances whose `pp1` is `30.0`. If there are no such instances, it returns an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for the pretty cool solution! And I guess if the property values are exactly unique for each instance, I can just  initialize it as  `example.pp1_lookup.update(pp1:self)` and after this `example.pp1_lookup[pp1]` will be the instance I want.

Comment: But will this work if I hope to select two properties?

Comment: By "... the property values are exactly unique for each instance...", I assume you mean no two instances share the same value for any given property? If so, then the change you need to make in the init method is `example.pp1_lookup[pp1] = self`, etc. And yes, the second approach doesn't help much if you want to look up based on two properties - in that case, you'd be better off just using the first (filtered list) approach.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible use for pandas DataFrames. If you like this solution,  I could show you an example of a DataFrame wrapper for your class. This advantages of this approach are that as your query needs grow you are able to express complex queries using pandas syntax.

```
import pandas as pd

ll = [i for i in range(0,100)]
for i in range(0,100):
    ll[i]=[i,i,i,i,i]
s = pd.DataFrame(ll,columns=['pp1','pp2','pp3','pp4','pp5'])

print s[s['pp1']==30]
```